# SignalR echo/negotiate not found?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

**Index.cshtml**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
    var connection = $.connection('/echo');

    connection.received(function (data) {
        $('#messages').append('<li>' + data + '</li>');
    });

    connection.start().done(function () {
        $("#broadcast").click(function () {
            connection.send($('#msg').val());
        });
    });

});
</script>
<input type="text" id="msg" />
<input type="button" id="broadcast" value="broadcast" />

<ul id="messages">
</ul>
```

**startup.cs**

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;
using UI;

namespace UI
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

**MyConnection.cs**

```
public class MyConnection : PersistentConnection
{
    protected override Task OnConnected(IRequest request, string connectionId)
    {
        return Connection.Send(connectionId, "Welcome!");
    }

    protected override Task OnReceived(IRequest request, string connectionId, string data)
    {
        return Connection.Broadcast(data);
    }
}
```

I m new to signalR. When I start the project I get following error:

> http://localhost:49820/echo/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.3&_=1383403303981 404 (Not Found)

[image]

What is the reason of this and how can I fix it? I cant find any solution about this problem. (.net framework 4.5 and signalR 2.0)

Comment: I guess you forgot to add <script src="/signalr/hubs/"></script> in your view.

Comment: @Lin, I added it but it does not work...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can not debug your code at the moment, but I think you should consider two possible problems.

1) You missed "$.connection.hub" in your start hub function. And when you call received method from server side to client side, you need to add 'connection.client.received'. It should be like below:

```
$(function () {
    var connection = $.connection('/echo');

    connection.client.received(function (data) {
        $('#messages').append('<li>' + data + '</li>');
    });

    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        $("#broadcast").click(function () {
            connection.send($('#msg').val());
        });
    });

});
```

2) You need to map your persistent connection. I believe in signalR 1.x should be something  like:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapConnection<MyConnection>("echo", "/echo");
```

But in SignalR 2.0 you need to do the following in your hub Startup class. Below is just an example.

```
public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR<MyConnection>("/echo");
        }
```

Comment: your second suggesstion works. I changed only this line `app.MapSignalR();` to `app.MapSignalR<MyConnection>("/echo");`